# Group built in types to category

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I've created the following program to assist me in some template stuff I'm working on.

The function `get_type` returns 0, 1, 2, 3 or `nullopt` corresponding to which `group` the argument `T` belongs to.

This is my first template style project, so I'm looking for any critique possible. (Note the functions are marked `static` intentionally, as this will only be used inside this particular file, and should not be visible to users.)

```
namespace ae
{
    namespace details
    {
        template <class T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static inline constexpr auto is_integer() noexcept
        {
            return std::is_same_v<T, short>
                || std::is_same_v<T, int>
                || std::is_same_v<T, long>
                || std::is_same_v<T, long long>
                || std::is_same_v<T, unsigned short>
                || std::is_same_v<T, unsigned int>
                || std::is_same_v<T, unsigned long>
                || std::is_same_v<T, unsigned long long>;
        }

        template <class T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static inline constexpr auto is_floating_point() noexcept
        {
            return std::is_same_v<T, float>
                || std::is_same_v<T, double>
                || std::is_same_v<T, long double>;
        }

        template <class T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static inline constexpr auto is_charachter() noexcept
        {
            return std::is_same_v<T, char>
                || std::is_same_v<T, unsigned char>
                || std::is_same_v<T, wchar_t>;
        }

        template <class T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static inline constexpr auto is_boolean() noexcept
        {
            return std::is_same_v<T, bool>;
        }

        // Returns 0 for integer, 1 for floating_point,
        // 2 for charachter, 3 for boolean, and nullopt otherwise
        template <class T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static inline constexpr auto get_type() noexcept
        {
            if constexpr (is_integer<T>())        
                return std::optional<unsigned int>(0u);
            else if constexpr (is_floating_point<T>()) 
                return std::optional<unsigned int>(1u);
            else if constexpr (is_charachter<T>())     
                return std::optional<unsigned int>(2u);
            else if constexpr (is_boolean<T>())       
                return std::optional<unsigned int>(3u);
            else return std::nullopt;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage

```
template <typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<ae::details::is_integer<T>(), T>::type test()
{
    // Do something if T is integer
}

template <typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<ae::details::is_charachter<T>(), T>::type test()
{
    // Do something if T is charachter
}

int main()
{
    test<int>(); //..

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a real test / use case please.

Comment: Added a quick example usage.

Comment: The `Example usage` from your first addition leaves me none the wiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `is_charachter` (which is misspelled; it should be `is_character`), you left out `signed char` (which is a distinct type from `char`). The same applies for all of the fixed width types (`char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`).

`get_type` returns some arbitrary magic number values.  You could create named constants to represent the type.  If you add a "unknown_type" value, then you wouldn't need to use `std::optional`.